# factorygirl sequence not working right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have this factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :from_sector, class: Sector do
    sequence(:name) { |n| name "gti#{n}" }                                                                                                                                   
  end
end
```

but when I do:

```
from = FactoryGirl.create(:from_sector)
from.name  #=>  <Sector id: 9, name: #<FactoryGirl::Declaration::Static:0x00000002d13650 @name=:name, @ignored=false, @value="gti1">, created_at: "2012-06-15 17:24:05", updated_at: "2012-06-15 17:24:05">
```

Shouldn't "from.name" return "gti1" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :from_sector, class: Sector do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "gti#{n}" }                                                                                                                                   
  end
end
```

Calling the *name* method mid-line was choking up FactoryGirl, hence the funny looking output.